# Room: Additional fields not showing on emulator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In my room application I started with the field new_pb which was working well. I am now trying to add pb_value and pb_details but these fields do not show on the emulator. Also, when I try to enter a new pb, nothing appears. It only shows the ones already created in the db. Migration has been added and version number updated.

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val newPbActivityRequestCode = 1
    private lateinit var pbViewModel: PbViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        val adapter = PbListAdapter(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        pbViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PbViewModel::class.java)

        pbViewModel.allPbs.observe(this, Observer { pbs -> pbs?.let { adapter.setPbs(it)}})

        val fab = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NewPbActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, newPbActivityRequestCode)
        }
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intentData: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData)

        if (requestCode == newPbActivityRequestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            intentData?.let { data ->
                val new_pb = NewPb(data.getIntExtra(
                    NewPbActivity.EXTRA_REPLY, 0),"", 0.0,  "")
                pbViewModel.insert(new_pb)
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                R.string.empty_not_saved,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
```

NewPbActivity

```
class NewPbActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var editNewPb: EditText

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_pb)
        editNewPb = findViewById(R.id.edit_new_pb)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_save)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val replyIntent = Intent()
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editNewPb.text)) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, replyIntent)
            } else {
                val new_pb = editNewPb.text.toString()
                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, new_pb)
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, replyIntent)
            }
            finish()
        }
    }
    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_REPLY = "com.example.android.NewPblistsql.REPLY"


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database is already created with table , then to add new fields to existing table, you need to fire alter query in room migration block which is equivalent to onUpgrade() .
Refer Android developer site for room migration if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have updated my post to show the db. I tried migration before but it still didn't show the new fields. I have changed this a few times but if you can make a suggestion on how to fix this to show the new fields, it would be appreciated. I also updated the version number to 2.

Comment: Your DB version should be 2,  alter query is allowed to add one column at a time, means you have to fire three queries one after another.for three columns. Also add logs or debug to identify what's happening

Comment: Thanks and I have tried all that you suggest. I have this logcat error: E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length.

Answer (score 0):

Change your DB version so your will called and do something like this

```
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBL_GPS_DATA);
 this.onCreate(db);//OP1
//OR OP2 alter table
 try {
            if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
//                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TBL_GPS_DATA + " ADD COLUMN " + COUNTRY + " TEXT DEFAULT 'INDIA'");
//                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TBL_GPS_DATA + " ADD COLUMN " + COUNTRY_FLAG + " TEXT DEFAULT '0' ");

                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TBL_GPS_DATA + " ADD COLUMN " + COUNTRY + " TEXT ");
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TBL_GPS_DATA + " ADD COLUMN " + COUNTRY_FLAG + " TEXT ");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("this is error due to onupgrade v ");
        }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my post to show the db. I tried migration before but it still didn't show the new fields. I have changed this a few times but if you can make a suggestion on how to fix this to show the new fields, it would be appreciated. I also updated the version number to 2